# User function in R quosure issue

Tags: r

I am using freq from library(summarytools) to create some frequencies.

Example:

```
mtcars %>%
  freq(mpg,
       cumul = FALSE,
       totals = TRUE)
```

I am trying to create a user function so I can loop through select vars to generate these tables:

```
create_freq <- function(v1) {
  v1 <- enquo(v1)
  out <- mtcars %>%
  freq(!!v1, 
       cumul = FALSE,
       totals = TRUE)
  return(out)
}


create_freq(mpg)
```

But I get this error that I cannot figure out, I think the closure isn't correct, but I don't know how to debug... help please?

```
Error in freq(., !!v1, cumul = FALSE, totals = TRUE) : 
  NULL is either NULL or does not exist
Called from: freq(., !!v1, cumul = FALSE, totals = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mtcars %>%freq(mpg,cumul = FALSE,totals = TRUE)` gives the same output as `freq(mtcars$mpg, cumul = FALSE, totals = TRUE`. So without making things complicated with NSE you may try.

```
library(summarytools)

create_freq <- function(v1) {
  freq(v1,cumul = FALSE, totals = TRUE)
}
```

For one variable -

```
create_freq(mtcars$mpg)
```

For more than one variable -

```
lapply(mtcars[1:2], create_freq)
```

Comment: thank you, but These two are producing different results! mtcars %>%
  freq(mpg,
       cumul = FALSE,
       totals = TRUE)   VS

lapply(c('mpg'), create_freq)

Comment: I would like to see the descriptive produced in the first one above, the lapply does something strange

Comment: You are using the function wrong. You should use `lapply(mtcars["mpg"], create_freq)` if you want to use it based on column names. Also you don't need `lapply` when using for only one variable you can do `create_freq(mtcars['mpg'])`. For more than one variable you can use `lapply` i.e `lapply(mtcars[c("mpg", "am")], create_freq)`

Comment: Oh! Thanks! Is there a way to run lapply via a vector, such as vct <- mtcars %>% names(.); I want to run this function over all the column in my data frame (or most of them, and there are a lot), ty!

Comment: @NewBee `create_freq(mtcars[vct], create_freq)`

Answer (score 3):

I do not know this function, but from what I searched this will give a similar result:

### Libraries

```
library(dplyr)
```

### Function

```
   create_freq <- function(df,grp_var){
      
      df %>% 
        count({{grp_var}} := as.character({{grp_var}})) %>% 
        mutate("%" = 100*n/sum(n)) %>% 
        {. ->>temp} %>% 
        bind_rows(
          temp %>% 
            group_by({{grp_var}} := "Total") %>% 
            summarise(across(.cols = where(is.numeric),.fns = sum))
        )
    }
```

### Example

```
    create_freq(mpg,cyl)


  cyl       n    `%`
  <chr> <int>  <dbl>
1 4        81  34.6 
2 5         4   1.71
3 6        79  33.8 
4 8        70  29.9 
5 Total   234 100
```